# use subquery in rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following **two sub queries:**

```
    @sub= ShareDetail.where(:dump_date_id=>2,:file_from_id=>1).select('TotalShares AS previous').group('previous')

    @sub1= ShareDetail.where(:dump_date_id=>1,:file_from_id=>1).select('TotalShares AS current').group('current')
```

**In model:**

```
  class ShareHolder < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :share_details,:dependent=>:destroy  
  end
```

I want to use these sub queries in

```
 @shareHolders= ShareHolder.where(:client_id=>session[:shareinvestor_user_id]).......
```

I have no idea how do i use these sub-queries. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) ?

```
class ShareHolder < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :share_details,:dependent=>:destroy
  scope :sub, -> { where(:dump_date_id=>2,:file_from_id=>1).select('TotalShares AS previous').group('previous') }
  scope :sub1, -> { where(:dump_date_id=>1,:file_from_id=>1).select('TotalShares AS current').group('current') }
end
```

Then you can use this:

```
@shareHolders= ShareHolder.where(:client_id=>session[:shareinvestor_user_id]).sub
```

**Update**

```
class ShareHolder < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :share_details,:dependent=>:destroy
end

class ShareDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :sub, -> { where(:dump_date_id=>2,:file_from_id=>1).select('TotalShares AS previous').group('previous') }
  scope :sub1, -> { where(:dump_date_id=>1,:file_from_id=>1).select('TotalShares AS current').group('current') }
end
```

And this:

```
@shareDetails= ShareHolder.find_by(client_id: session[:shareinvestor_user_id]).share_details.sub
```

Comment: getting error like 'Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'previous''